# How to save App language in NSUserDefaults Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am working on an app which runs in 2 languages **English** and **Arabic**. So user can select his desired language and app is displayed in that language.

I am using `localization` for displaying static texts. I have created localization string files in English and Arabic.

So now, I want to save the language selected by the user in `NSUserDefaults` and use this to implement `localization`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

do like

```
func isDeviceLanguageRTL() -> Bool {
return (NSLocale.characterDirectionForLanguage(NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]) == .RightToLeft)
}
```

**Initially Check may Be your app language is Arabic or English**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

if self.isDeviceLanguageRTL() 
{
 // it is Arabic

}
}
```

**Secondary on your button action save**

set tag for your button for e.g eng = 0 and arabic = 1;

ok on that assumption do like

```
func  buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)  
{
   let userDefaults =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  if sender.tag == 1
 {
   // english
  userDefaults.setObject("En", forKey: "AppleLanguages")
 } else
 {
  //arbaic
   userDefaults.setObject("AR", forKey: "AppleLanguages")
 }
}
```

**retrieve**

```
 if let getlan = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("AppleLanguages") as? String {
      if getlan == "En" { 
              //English
         }
         else { 
              //Arabic
         }
   }
```

Comment: Actually I have two buttons. One for English and another one for Arabic. So suppose user selects English, I want to save that in UserDefaults. Is there any specific key for language while saving to UserDefaults? I am actually new to Swift, So I don't have much knowledge about basics. It would be great if you could help me out